# How to target cloned element in DOM (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_content">
            <div class="box_price">180</div>
            <div class="box_button">Click me</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_content">
            <div class="box_price">130</div>
            <div class="box_button">Click me</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_content">
            <div class="box_price">270</div>
            <div class="box_button">Click me</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

</div>

<div class="cost"></div>
```

So I've cloned and appended some of the .box divs in jQuery from .main to .container using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
    $(".box_button").click(function(){

        var box_content = $(this).parents('.box').clone(); //Box is cloned
        var price = $(box_content).find(".box_price");

        $(price).toggleClass('box_price sc_box_price'); //Class changed to sc_box_price
        $(box_content).append('.container'); //Box is appended
    });
});
```

Before appending, I changed the class of the child element .box_price to .sc_box_price.

I have another code, which is supposed to calculate the sum of all .sc_box_price and append it to .cost.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";

    var box_price = $(".sc_box_price");
    var total = 0;

    $(box_price).each(function(){
        total += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    $('.cost').prepend("<div class='cost'>"+total+"</div>");
    console.log(total);
});
```

For some reason I am unable to target .sc_box_price. Perhaps it is because .sc_box_price is not actually added to the DOM? How do I fix this?

Comment: Please check that you do not change class only after the item has been cloned. I'm expecting changes to the original object after cloning will not reflect on the clone.

Comment: Don't you want instead: `$(box_content).appendTo('.container');` ??? And fyi, `box_content` is already jq object, so no need to wrap it again, e.g: `var price = box_content.find(".box_price");` and btw, `price` is already jq object, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `append()` your need to use `appendTo` to append your cloned box.

There is difference between appendTo and append i.e

```
take this new thing and appendTo an already existing thing
vs
take already existing thing and append this new thing
```

Thats why you need to use `appendTo()`

now after appending add your other code into the `onClick event after appendTo statement` Also instead of appending a div everytime your can just change the text of the `cost` div. I suppose this is what your want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".box_button").click(function(){
        
        var box_content = $(this).parents('.box').clone(); //Box is cloned
        var price = $(box_content).find(".box_price");

        $(price).toggleClass('box_price sc_box_price'); //Class changed to sc_box_price
        
        $(box_content).appendTo('.container'); //Box is appended
      
         var box_price = $(".sc_box_price");
          var total = 0;

          $(box_price).each(function(){
              total += parseInt($(this).text());
          });
          
          $('.cost').text(total);
          
          });
    
    
});
```

```css
.cost {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_content">
            <div class="box_price">180</div>
            <div class="box_button">Click me</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_content">
            <div class="box_price">130</div>
            <div class="box_button">Click me</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_content">
            <div class="box_price">270</div>
            <div class="box_button">Click me</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
   
</div>

<div class="container">

</div>

<div class="cost"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `append` call is backwards.  Try this.

Please note, though, that the appended "Click me" elements will have no `click` events associated with them. Is this your intention?

Also, I think you may want to use an `html` call on `$('.cost')` instead of `append`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";

    $(".box_button").click(function(){

        var box_content = $(this).parents('.box').clone(); //Box is cloned
        var price = $(box_content).find(".box_price");

        $(price).toggleClass('box_price sc_box_price'); //Class changed to sc_box_price
        // $(box_content).append('.container'); //Box is appended
        $('.container').append(box_content); //Box is appended

        calculate_price();
    });
});

function calculate_price() {
    var box_price = $(".sc_box_price");
    var total = 0;

    $(box_price).each(function(){
        total += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    $('.cost').html("<div class='cost'>"+total+"</div>"); // formerly: $('.cost').append
    console.log(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_content">
            <div class="box_price">180</div>
            <div class="box_button">Click me</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_content">
            <div class="box_price">130</div>
            <div class="box_button">Click me</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_content">
            <div class="box_price">270</div>
            <div class="box_button">Click me</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

</div>

<div class="cost"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many erros in your code. What was the idea? Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
    $(".box_button").click(function(){

      var box_content = $(this).parents('.box').clone();
      var price = box_content.find(".box_price");

      price.toggleClass('box_price sc_box_price'); 
      
      $('.container').append(price);  
      //box_content.append('.container'); //Box is appended
      
      var box_price = $(".sc_box_price");
      var total = 0;

      box_price.each(function(){
        total += parseInt($(this).text());
      });
      
      $('.cost').html("Total:"+total);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_content">
            <div class="box_price">180</div>
            <div class="box_button">Add to Cart</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_content">
            <div class="box_price">130</div>
            <div class="box_button">Add to Cart</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box_content">
            <div class="box_price">270</div>
            <div class="box_button">Add to Cart</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  </br>
  Cart:
</div>

<div class="cost"></div>
```